Interpretation of the components of the Einstein tensor? (for visual thinkers)
I am trying to understand what the different components of the Einstein tensor correspond to, and how they can be interpreted in physics.
So we consider the tensor:
$$G_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}G_{tt}& G_{tx} & G_{ty} & G_{tz}\\ G_{xt} & G_{xx} & G_{xy} & G_{xz}\\ G_{yt} & G_{yx} & G_{yy} & G_{yz} \\ G_{zt} & G_{zx} & G_{zy} & G_{zz} \end{pmatrix}$$
in local 3+1 coordinates, with one coordinate that can be interpreted as time $t$, and the other 3 as locally cartesian spatial coordinates $x, y, z$. The mental picture I'm starting with is roughly something along the line of that:

I am trying to get a sense of what the following components mean in terms of geometry and physics:

$G_{tt}$: time component
$G_{ti}$: mixed space-time components (first line)
$G_{it}$: mixed space-time components (first column)
$G_{ii}$: diagonal spatial components
$G_{ij}$: non-diagonal spatial components

I don't ask the question in terms of algebraic or symbolic rules, or how to make the calculations, I am trying to get a mental picture of what the components correspond to (even if the mental picture is not 100% accurate). The kind of explanation I'm looking for would illustrate the difference between several values of each of the components I listed : what it means when they are:

equal to zero
when they are non-zero
when they are small (compared to other components)
when they are large (compared to other components)
and when they would go to infinity.

(in total it's 5 types of components times 5 categories of values). Drawings or illustrations in terms of physics would help. That would help a lot my geometric intuition of the mathematical object it represents.

If they go to infinity, we have issues, since in the right system of units (and dividing by $8\pi$), the Einstein tensor equals the stress-energy tensor…

I know, but this is typically a symbolic answer ;) I know it breaks, I know it may be absurd, but what I'm interested in is "how" it breaks when the value get higher and higher. If I had to explain it with drawings to an 8-years old, that's what I'm looking for.

@controlgroup:  It could also just mean that there's a coordinate singularity of some kind.

Yes yes, that makes sense. Given that the Einstein and stress-energy-momentum tensors are only different by a constant factor, I might suggest simply equating their meanings and saying “the Einstein tensor tells you how energy and momentum and pressure are arranged in space”, but that might not be what you’re looking for.

@MichaelSeifert Also pretty bad, but true.

Remember the metric is symmetric so your second and third components are the same thing, in reality there are only 10 independent components out of a possible 16. This might help a bit too The Metric Tensor.

You might be interested in the ADM formalism, which describes the metric, not the Einstein tensor directly. It does a $3+1$ split of spacetime into a set of hypersurfaces "stacked" in the time direction, and where you can view various components of the metric as the lapse (a scalar controlling the rate at which time passes between hypersurfaces), the shift (a 3-vector controlling how hypersurfaces are stiched together) and the induced metric (describing the intrinsic geometry of the hypersurfaces).

In the ADM formalism (which gives you a route to the Hamiltonian formulation of GR), you can reinterpret Einstein's equations as 4 (first class) constraint equations associated with diffeomorphism (coordinate) invariance, and 6 remaining equations in the remaining 6 unknowns. 4 of the unknowns can fixed by gauge (coordinate/diffeomorphism) invariance, leaving 2 independent unknowns and 2 remaining equations, which describe the two propagating degrees of freedom of the graviton. (Or, classical gravitational waves, if you want to avoid quantum language).
